# Forcing whitespace in Bash arrays being passed into grep

Tags: arrays, bash, grep, whitespace

I have a pretty simple bash script that should grep a file for multiple phrases that I want to flag.

It works up until a point, but I am falling over when I want to grep for ' print ' or ' puts ' (note the whitespace before and after the word).

The grep is ignoring the whitespace in the input.

Here is my code (stuff that isn't relevant has been cut out)

```
#!/bin/sh

bad_phrases=('console.log(' 'binding.pry' ':focus,' 'alert(' ' print ' ' puts ')
bad_phrase_found=false

FILE='my_test_file.txt'

for bad_phrase in ${bad_phrases[*]} ; do
  if grep -q "$bad_phrase" $FILE ; then
      bad_phrase_found=true
      echo "A '$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 1)$bad_phrase$(tput sgr0)' was found in $(tput bold)$(tput setaf 5)$FILE$(tput sgr0)"
  fi
done

if $bad_phrase_found ; then
  exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

I have looked at setting IFS to '~' and splitting the array up that way, but that killed the grep command completely.

The example output of the script is;

'print' was found in my_test_file.txt

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried changing `${bad_phrases[*]}` for `${bad_phrases[@]}`?

Comment: Yes - it made no difference unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `"${bad_phrases[@]}"`. Don't forget the double quotes. You should always make it a habit to quote all your variables in order to suppress [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

```
for bad_phrase in "${bad_phrases[@]}" ; do
  if grep -q "$bad_phrase" "$FILE" ; then
      bad_phrase_found=true
      echo "A '$(tput bold)$(tput setaf 1)$bad_phrase$(tput sgr0)' was found in $(tput bold)$(tput setaf 5)$FILE$(tput sgr0)"
  fi
done
```